Microsoft Entra custom scope authentication
I am swapping my in house SSO solution over to Microsoft Entra. I currently have stateless authentication on my express node web app, where I'm verifying a JWT, in a cookie, on every request and refresh the token when needed.
I now want to integrate my application with Microsoft Entra to handle logins and user management so I'm trying to copy what I currently have and swap Microsoft Entra as my auth provider instead of my own.
I'm now having a hard time trying to figure out what tokens I need from Entra. Can I just use the idToken? That does seem right. The access token is for the MS Graph API so I can't use that.
I think I'm overthinking it but I setup my SSO app in the Azure Portal and what I came up with was:

use a custom scope during auroization code flow
set a cookie with access token on successful login
using Microsoft jwks endpoint to get public signing keys
verify access tokens with kid and issuer on every request

It all works great.... my problem is this token only lives for a short while and you can't configure the expiration in the Azure Portal and I can't see a way to refresh it.
Am I going about it the correct way? I kind of only need Microsoft Entra for login, there is no real need to use the MS Graph API at all so I don't need an access token for that.
The only information I can find is all about access tokens when accessing the graph, which I don't need. I understand I can't mix scopes for different resources so I've been reading about having two tokens, one for MS Graph and another for my private resource server but I don't know what benefits having the access token for the graph are.
Can anyone provide any advice or examples of a similar setup to mine and how you're using Microsoft Entra's SSO?
